# Get a string from an array inside an array

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a function that returns an array from the database from which I have to display some data into the view.

If I do

```
print "<pre>";
print_r($names);
exit();
```

on the variable that stores the data it returns this:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
        (
            [nume] => Eugen
        )
[1] => Array
        (
            [nume] => Roxanescu
        )
[2] => Array
        (
            [nume] => Georgiana
        )
[3] => Array
        (
            [nume] => Andrei
        )
)
```

I can't change the function I talk about in any way, I need to store each name in a different variable. At the end it should look like this:

```
name1 = "Eugen"
name2 = "Roxanescu"
name3 = "Georgiana"
name4 = "Andrei"
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Have you tried `$name1 = $names[0]['nume'];` and so on?

Comment: So this array is a result of a database query correct? how are you making that query? can you provide that code? also, can you provide the structure of your db table?

Comment: Why would you want to store the names in different variables? I think you are trying work harder then you should. consider iterating through your results array to access the names.

Comment: The query looks like this: "SELECT `nume` FROM `rummy_users` LEFT JOIN `rummy_games` ON `rummy_users`.`id_user`=`rummy_games`.`id_user` WHERE `rummy_games`.`id_joc`=".$id_joc.".

Comment: I only have to display 4 each time so it is a lot simpler for me as I am a beginner. Any tips are welcome but I'm not sure I'm able to make an iteration yet.

Comment: @Stuart Wagner it actually worked fine with  $name1 = $names[0]['nume'];  Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1):

You could assign a variable the data of your array;

```
<?php
    $name1=$names[0];
    $name2=$names[1];
    $name3=$names[2];
    $name4=$names[3];

    echo $name1." ".$name2." ".$name3." ".$name4;
?>
```

Comment: Haha thanks! I have never thought of this way but now that I see it I realize I should've known it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Note entirely sure why you want to do this... But here's a function that should do what you're looking for.

This answer uses dynamic variable assignment, creating a new variable with a string ( $"name1", $"name2", etc ).

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($names); $i++) {
  $var_name = "name".$i;
  $$var_name = $names[$i]['nume'];
}

var_dump(get_defined_vars());

$name1, $name2, $name3 ... < count($names)
```

Comment: The purpose is an application to keep the score record while you play rummy (if you know the game, something like whist or rentz or something simmilar). You have to select the players from a dropdown list and in this application there are always 4 players so I have no reason to complicate the code. Still, thank you very much!

Comment: @VladEugenNitu, this is the right answer for what you've asked and the right way to code. Learn how to make code reusable and parametric as soon as possible, you won't regret it!

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = array();
array_walk($names, function ($value, $key) use (&$result) {
    $result[ 'name' . $key ] = $value['name'];
});
var_dump($result);
```

Comment: Even this is a simple question, please add some contextual comments in order to help others that have beginner skills.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use an array and reference to each element of it as a variable, if it's really necessary.

```
$result = array();
foreach ($names as $n) {
    array_push($result, $n['nume']);
    echo "name".array_search($n['nume'], $result)." = ".$n['nume'];
}
```